# Controlsend to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried a number of things to make this work and all have failed:

- `ControlSend,, ^f, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`
- `ControlSend,, ^f, ahk_exe Code.exe`

Both of the above failed to open the find bar in VSCode.

I had a similar issue once,  when I was trying to use `ControlSend` with Firefox and adding `ahk_parent` worked then:

- `ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^f, ahk_exe Code.exe`
- `ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^f, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1`

Sadly, both of the above also failed to trigger anything.

I searched around but was not able to find anything for `ControlSend` with VSCode.

Has anyone had any success using `ControlSend` with VSCode?

Any help would be really wellcome

Answer (score 1):

I tried `ControlSend`ing various commands to VSC. This seems to be a problem only to certain commands (another one is `^d`), while other commands such as `^n` work with no hitches.

Some things I noticed:

- VSC **must** be activated (i.e. in focus) so `ControlSend` can work at all.
- When debugging your script from VSC, sending only one `^f` doesn't seem to work. However, funnily, when you send `^f` twice, VSC always registers it.

Here's a "crude but it works" solution:

```
; Improves reliability - the script holds down Shift for 50 ms before sending f
SetKeyDelay,, 50
WinActivate, ahk_exe Code.exe
ControlSend,, ^f, ahk_exe Code.exe
ControlSend,, ^f, ahk_exe Code.exe
```

If you plan to launch your script as an .exe or outside VSC, then the second `ControlSend` can be omitted. But sending it twice doesn't cause any harm. The main drawback is that VSC will be activated (brought to front and then focused).

Comment: Hey Thanks allot for this. Your code works though its not what I am looking. I was looking to avoid activating VSCode window.  I asked this question on the official forum and got a decent answer. For your own benifit I will share it with you. Thanks! [Link](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=111936&p=498120#p498120)